# Why do the data objects takes up different sizes in python

Tags: python

## 1st Approach

For example:

```
data = b"abc\npqr\nxyz\n"
fp = open("C:/temp/abc.txt", 'wb')
fp.write(data)
fp.close()
```

If I right click on this file -> properties, the bytes occupied would be 12.
But if I go with

## 2nd Approach

```
import sys

print(sys.getsizeof(data))
```

or

```
print(data.__sizeof__())
```

it gives me different as compared to first approach.
Shouldn't all of these commands give you how much bytes they take up in memory?

Comment: What are the sizes that the second approach gives you?

Comment: 29 for 2nd approach

Comment: No, a *bytes object* is not the same as the raw bytes you write to a file.

Comment: Do you mean raw bytes as normal way we could put string to a file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code shows something else about sizes of data in memory:

```
import sys

data1 = b"abc\npqr\nxyz\n"
data2 = b"abc\npqr\nxyz\nghi\n"


print(sys.getsizeof(data1),data1.__sizeof__())
print(sys.getsizeof(data2),data2.__sizeof__())
```

Output:

```
29 29
33 33
```

It seems that `data2` is 4 bytes larger, which is expected.

This means that some types have an overhead associated with them in memory.

I noticed that you didn't relay to us **all** the properties of the file that you created.

If I recreate the file you wrote, I can also see that it has 12 bytes in it, but on my Windows 10 machine it also says that the size on disk is 4k bytes. Now that's a large overhead! So a 17 byte overhead in memory is not so bad.

Comment: The same it shows me on my windows 8 machine 4.00KB, 4096 bytes (size on disk), So the 29/33 o/p is the main memory's bytes it is taking up and 4.00KB is the overall data of the file object on the disk is that what you meant??

Comment: Yes, that's right. Now you know that the essential data takes up 12 (or 16 in my example) bytes, but the overhead in memory means that it takes 29 (or 33) bytes altogether. And on disk, the file you wrote, contains 12 bytes of actual data, but occupies 4kBytes of physical disk space.